# Natural Language Processing technique for rephrasing question-answer pairs as full sentence?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, nlp-question-answering

Is there an NLP technique for rephrasing question-answer pairs as a full and grammatically correct sentence? For example:

Question: Where does Joe live?

Answer: Joe lives in Los Angeles.

I’ve looked into Answer Ellipsis, which is essentially the opposite of this issue and what most Machine Reading Comprehension or Question Answering systems already generate. For example, the answer to the above with answer ellipsis would be “Los Angeles”.

For the sake of reader comprehension, I want to turn question-answer pairs into something understandable. What techniques exist to do this?